# How to specify OAuth audience (audience:server:client_id returns invalid_scope)

Tags: windows, oauth, google-signin

We're writing Windows app and we also have backend server. And we want to implement Google Login. So the Windows app asks the user, it receives the JWT token and passes it to our server. I the token, there are 2 keys: `aud` and `azp`. On our other platoforms (iOS, Android), the `azp` is the *OAuth Client ID* of the application from Google Cloud Console and `aud` is *OAuth Client ID* for our server. But on Windows, they are both same. On other platform, this is handled by libraries provided by Google, but on Windows, we're using *low-level* HTTP. But we can't find a way to specify the `aud`. How can we do it?

EDIT: I found out about `audience:server:client_id:...` in `scope`, but it doesn't work for me either. It gives me `Error: invalid_scope`.

This is the request (using HTTPie):

```
http -v https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth client_id==windows-ios-app-client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com redirect_uri==my.bundle.id: response_type==code 'scope==audience:server:client_id:server-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com'

GET /o/oauth2/auth?client_id=windows-ios-app-client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=my.bundle.id%3A&response_type=code&scope=audience%3Aserver%3Aclient_id%3Aserver-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: accounts.google.com
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.2
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think we should provide this scope while you request for token. This is  probably automatically done if we use Google/Sign-In library, provided that we set the server client id.</strike>

```
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].serverClientID = @"YOUR_SERVER_CLIENT_ID_HERE"
```

By the way, If any am looking for a way to implement the same using AppAuth. I did not find any solution yet.

Send the web client id as a parameter `audience=WEB_CLIENT_ID` when requesting token endpoint.